# Is it possible to assign a value without creating an intermediate variable?

Tags: ios, uitableview, variables

I have custom UITableViewCell with property UITextField

```
MOProfileSettingsCell *cell = [_customCells objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *str = cell.textField.text;
```

can I modify my syntax like:

```
NSString *str = (MOProfileSettingsCell*)[_customCells objectAtIndex:0].textField.text;
```

I know that example not right but...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need more brackets, like this:

```
((MOProfileSettingsCell*)[_customCells objectAtIndex:0]).textField.text
```

But yes, please use the first way in your code — otherwise it's hard to read!

Comment: Cool! I thought right then that I can do this assignment) Yes is that hard to read! Thx

Comment: it's seriously hard to read. `NSString *value = [[(id)self.customCells[0] textField] text]` also works mayhaps (note abbreviation `str` isn't recommended)?

Comment: `str` that for example, i'm not use, variables must named by logic in case))) Hah, how Xcode know `id` is my custom cell in my case? Thx for another syntax, don't know that!